# Why isn't my select2 autocomplete method getting executed?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I'm trying to implement the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) on my master layout of my ASP.NET MVC 4 website.

I want it to, as soon as the user starts typing (minimum of 2 letters), call my method to query the database using the letters the user has already typed. Except, when I start typing, my method never gets called. I threw in some alerts and I'm able to see what I'm typing, but the select2 isn't firing, I think.

Here's the script and css references in the  tag:

```
<script src="/Content/select2/select2.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Here's the search box in my layout.cshtml file:

```
<div class="navbar-header hidden-xs pull-right" style="padding-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
  <input id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." type="text" data-autocomplete-url="/Home/AutoFillValues" />
</div>
```

And here's the bottom of my layout page where the select2 stuff appears:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").select2({
            placeholder: "Search...",
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax: {
                url: "~/Home/AutoFillSearch",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: function(search) {
                    return {
                        q: search
                    };
                },
                results: function(search, page) {
                    return { results: data.Results };
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Lastly, here's my controller method (I'm not worried about the code here yet, I just want to see my breakpoint get hit at the first line...):

```
public ActionResult AutoFillValues()
{
    // Get all wrestlers and all teams
    var players = _playerRepo.Query().Where(w => w.Division == "Division I" && w.Conference != null);
    var schools = players.Select(w => w.School).Distinct();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    foreach (var school in schools)
    {
        var hyperlinkFormat = "<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>";

        //@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Model.Team.Name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        list.Add(string.Format(hyperlinkFormat, string.Format(RosterPath, school), string.Format(RosterText, school)));
    }

    foreach (var player in playerss)
    {
        var hyperlinkFormat = "<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>";

        //@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Model.Team.Name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        list.Add(string.Format(hyperlinkFormat, string.Format(RosterPath, player.School), string.Format(RosterText, player.School)));
    }

    return Json(list.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any messages in the console

Comment: No. I used to have an "onkeydown" event to test it, and that was the only time anything happened when I typed in the field. No events occur now. When I first open the console window, there's an error that says: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" and it's throwing it on jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js line 115

Comment: Try fixing that and see if it resolves your issue.  If that error is on the select 2 field it might be causing the weird behavior

Comment: $("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.href,
            type: "GET",
            data: []
        });
    });

Comment: @drneel I'm going to try updating jquery tonight because that's the issue with the above comment/error that I posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade to jQuery 2.1 (because of the issue with version 1.9 and the .live/.on functions) in order for my select2 to start firing.

Now I just need to get my select2 styled...